# Custom Master page will not visible in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sandbox-solution, custom-masterpage

I have created a solution(sandbox solution) for applying custom master page on feature activation.Custom Master page is not visible in Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Element.xml

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" RootWebOnly="TRUE" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
<File Path="MasterPages\custom.master" Url="MasterPages/custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
```

The master page is visible in **_catalogs/masterpage** but not in designer. see in image:
[image]
[image]

I have tried with the check in and approved master page then also it will not visible.

guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the master page was deployed by a sandbox solution please make sure that the master page is checked in and approved. SharePoint doesn't check in and approve files that was deployed by a sandbox solution. Also make sure that the correct content type is assigned. because otherwise you won't see it too.

To set the content type of the master page on deployment correct you just need to simply add the following inside the

```
<Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_masterpage_name;" />
```

If the master page is a farm  you should also add the content type but it will be checked in automatically. I hope you are on root level of your site collection because the master page will not deployed to the sub sites.

In SharePoint Designer you also have two different approaches to find the master page.
Approach 1:
Use the Master Page Entry on the navigation pane left. The Master Page will only show up if content type ins correctly set.

Approach 2:
Go to "All Files" -> _catalogs -> masterpage

By using approach two you will see the same amount of files that you can review in SharePoint. You will also find the article pages in there.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/23ab5b3e-2a88-4df1-8f7e-752f4f63dfe6/deployed-custom-master-page-not-visible-in-designer?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: After the Checked In and Publish the custom master page, I'm trying to approve the custom master page but it will generate exception for that. and your first option will not work for me event if I have checked In and publish the master page. Second is working...What I need to do for first option will work for me?